# getting distance matrix and features matrix from word2vec model

Tags: python, k-means, gensim, word2vec

I have generated a word2vec model using gensim for  a huge corpus and I need to cluster the vocabularies using k means clustering for that i need:

1. cosine distance matrix (word to word, so the size of the matrix the number_of_words x number_of_words )
2. features matrix (word to features, so the size of the matrix is the number_of_words x number_of_features(200) )

for the feature matrix i tried to use x=model.wv and I got the object type as gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors and its much smaller than what I expected a feature matrix will be

is there a way to use this object directly to generate the k-means clustering ?

Comment: Could you please add some code and expected/actual output?

Answer (score 2):

In gensim's Word2Vec model, the raw `number_of-words x number_of_features` numpy array of word vectors is in `model.wv.vectors`. (In older Gensim versions, the `.vectors` property was named `.syn0` matching the original Google `word2vec.c` naming).

You can use the `model.wv.key_to_index` dict (previously `.vocab`) to learn the string-token-to-array-slot assignment, or the `model.wv.index_to_key` list (previously `.index2word`) to learn the array-slot-to-word assignment.

The pairwise distances aren't pre-calculated, so you'd have to create that yourself. And with typical vocabulary sizes, it may be impractically large. (For example, with a 100,000 word vocabulary, storing all pairwise distances in the most efficient way possible would require roughly `100,000^2 * 4 bytes/float / 2 = 20GB` of addressable space.